# Ошибка табуляции, не понимаю, где накосячил

Tags: python, python-3.x

Писал программу и решил перенести кусочек кода, после чего начались проблемы с табуляцией - стала вылетать TabError, причину которой нигде найти не могу... И что бы я не использовал для написания строки, -пробелы или табы- ничего не помогает... Пожалуйста, скажите мне - в чем проблема? Что делаю не так? 
Проблема в 94 строке.

```
inp=[1,0,1,'!',1,'!!',1,'!!!'] #number input
min=0
max=0
for_binar=''
binar_part=[]
x=0
for_binar_add=''
binar_part_add=0
for_trans=0
add_num=len(inp)//3
inp_min=0
inp_max=0
E=''
X=1
trans_bin=''
binly=0
alphabet_rev=["£","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y",'z'," "]
rev_num=0
F=''
next=''
def bin_process(count):
    for i in range(inp_min,count*2,2):
            inp_max=i
            inp_min=inp_max-2
            D+=trans_bin[i]
    return(D)

bin_inp=[]
bin_end=0
counter=0

for inp_val in inp:
    #print (inp_val)
    if inp_val=='!'*X:

        inp_max=inp.index(inp_val)
        #print('inp_max=',inp_max,'\ninp_val=',inp_val,type(inp_val))
        for process in range(inp_min,inp_max):
            #print(process,inp_min,inp_max)
            E+=str(inp[inp_min])
            #print(f'E, {inp[inp_min]}')
            inp_min+=1
        inp_min+=1
        X+=1

        bin_inp=list(E)
        #bin_inp.reverse()
        for bin_count in bin_inp:

            bin_end+=2**counter*int(bin_count)
            counter+=1


        #print(f'E ={E} and its type is {type(E)},bin_inp={bin_inp}')
        print(f'Your decoded input: {bin_end}')
        trans_bin+=str(bin_end)
        counter=0
        bin_end=0
        E=''
trans_bin=list(trans_bin)        
trans_bin.reverse()
print(f'Prefinal={trans_bin}')

inp_min=0
binly=len(trans_bin)%2  #Чётно ли количество символов в списке
#print(binly)
count=len(trans_bin)/2   #Количество пар.
#print(count)
D=''
counter_2=0
inp_max=int(count*2)

if int(count)>0:
    if binly==0:
        bin_process(int(count))
    else:
        for i in range(inp_min,inp_max,2):
            inp_min=inp_max-2*int(count)            

            print('ok')
            print(inp_min,inp_max)
            print(i,D)
            for rand in range(inp_min,i):
                print(f'rand now:{rand}')
                D+=trans_bin[rand]
                counter_2+=1
                if counter_2%2==0:
                    print('finding problems...')
                    if int(D)>len(alphabet_rev)-1: #сли получившееся число больше количества элементов алфавита...
                        D=list(tuple(D))
                        x=D[len(D)-1] #x= последнее значение списка
                        D.pop()
                        print("oops")

                ###Ошибка ниже, две строки###
                    #else:
                        #print('problems not found')


print(str(D))





       # D+=trans_bin[inp_max+1]
#print(D)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код в порядок. Дело в том, что в таком виде его (и ошибку как следствие) нельзя запустить (`NameError` на 9 строке). Посмотрите, пожалуйста, раздел справки [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Внести улучшения в вопрос Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Прописав в inp массив из нескольких чисел, всё запустилось. Попробуйте использовать нормальный редактор кода, типа pycharm'a или vs code.

Comment: У вас в коде отступы где-то пробелами, где-то табами: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9z7E.png (точки - это пробелы, стрелки - табы). Во избежание таких проблем настройте редактор, чтобы отступы добавлялись только пробелами.